# Finding subset of a set

Tags: python

Here is my program to Check if arr1 is a subset of arr2. But there is a bug when arr2 is not a subset of arr1. I am trying to implement the algorithm of it in python. But what is the best way to if it is not in the frequency table?

```py
def isSubset(arr1, arr2):
    frequency = {}

    for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
        if arr1[i] in frequency:
            frequency[arr1[i]] = frequency[arr1[i]] + 1
        else:
            frequency[arr1[i]] = 1

    for i in range(0, len(arr2)):
        if frequency[arr2[i]] > 0:
            frequency[arr2[i]] -= 1
        else:
            return False

    return True

isSubset(['a'],['b']) # KeyError: 'b'
```

Comment: Check if arr1 is a subset of arr2

Comment: Why don't you use the builtin set?

Comment: The most Pythonic way to check for a subset is to use... a set, where there is already a `issubset` method.

Comment: I wish to implement the algorithm...

Comment: ```for i in range(0, len(arr1)):``` could be replace by `for arr in arr1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the `KeyError` that your code is getting, you can use the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to return a default value of 0 when given a non-existing key.

Change:

```
if frequency[arr2[i]] > 0:
```

to:

```
if frequency.get(arr2[i], 0) > 0:
```