# How to find subset of a set without knowing the subset or parent set values

Tags: python, minesweeper

I have two sets:

```
a = {x,x,x,x}
b = {x,x,x,x,x}
```

with x meaning unknown values

The exact arrangements or length or values of each set `(a or b)` are not fixed until they've been discovered. I am not able to know what exact values or which would be a subset of which but I need to be able to detect and perform some action once either is a subset of the other.

I understand I could do this using:

```
if a <= b or b <= a:
```

But the issue is that below this `if statement`, I must be sure of which one is a subset of the other because I perform some functions with the subset and the set such as **filtering out the subset from the set**. There's no room for maybes, like an `if statement`. And I do not want to write duplicate code.

How do you suggest I go about this?

Sources I have checked:
[Finding all the subsets of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728972/finding-all-the-subsets-of-a-set)
[Finding subset of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822286/finding-subset-of-a-set)

Comment: If you've established that `a <= b or b <= a`, then `min(a, b, key=len)` will return whichever of the sets is smaller.

Comment: @slothrop does this work for list types also? That is if a and b are list

Comment: `a <= b` doesn't work for lists. You'd need to do `set(a) <= set(b)` etc to check whether the contents of one list are a subset of the other.

Comment: *"filtering out the subset from the set"* - Do you mean modify the existing set object or create a new one with the filtered result?

Comment: @KellyBundy Create a new one

Comment: Can't you just do `a ^ b` for that then, without knowing which one is the subset? Do you need to know for the other "some functions"?

Comment: @KellyBundy what does `a ^ b` do?

Comment: If you need to know which is the subset, then use an if/else.  `if a < b: ... elif b < a: ...`

Comment: See its [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference).

Comment: @JohnGordon You're missing the case where they're equal.

Comment: @JohnGordon I said no duplicate code. The actions I perform on both cases `if a < b: ... elif b < a: ...` are the same.

Comment: @KellyBundy The question title specifically says "subset".  I assume equal sets are not subsets.

Comment: The `if a < b` block does not need much code; simply assign two variables `superset = b` and `subset = a`, and the reverse for `elif b < a`.  Then in the real processing section, operate on those variables instead of `a` and `b` directly.

Comment: @JohnGordon Equal sets are subsets of each other. Or in other words, a set is a subset of itself. You're thinking of *proper* subsets, which they didn't say.

Comment: What does *"There's no room for maybes, like an if statement"* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @slothrop. This works! No matter the values of any of the list or set.

```
smaller_set = list(min(set(a), set(b), key=len))
larger_set = list(max(set(a), set(b), key=len))
print(smaller_set,'smaller_set')
print(larger_set,'larger_set')
```

Comment: To avoid calling `min` and `max` which feels redundant as there are only two values, you can also go with something like `smaller, larger = (a, b) if len(set(a)) < len(set(b)) else (b, a)` (credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/3674252/6045800)